# hierarchy and inheritence of css classes between css definition files in an application

Tags: css, angular

I am curious about how CSS files propagate through an angular application.  I have at the highest level my src folder, which includes styles.css.  I know the styles defined there apply to the entire application.  Under that is the app folder, which has app.component.css.  That has two subcomponents, alpha.component and beta.component, each in their own folders (alpha and beta, respectively).  alpha has gamma and delta subfolders, each which their own components defined with css, html, and ts files.  If I define a class in alpha.component.css, and use that class in gamma.component.html, will the rules from alpha.component.css apply to those instances of my classes?  Likewise, if a class is defined in app.component.css, will it apply across all the html files in the app?

Comment: If there is a problem with the question, please leave a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which ever style we defined in css a file will only get applied to the componet they belong to. This is called `View Encapsulation` in Angular.

when you inspect element you can see some weird tags like `.my-nav[_ngcontent-c0]` is added by angular which is unique to each component class. thats how angular know which style to apply. you can override this feature by

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-xxx',
  templateUrl: './xxx.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./xxx.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
 })
```

> ViewEncapsulation.None needs to be imported from core

And the global `styles.css` file in `src` folder will apply to the whole project. this behavior has nothing to do with the folder structure of app. Global styles are added in `.angular-cli.json` file under `styles`

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
    "../node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css",
    "styles.css"
  ]
```

as you can see i have added my global css last, which has the higher priority.

Comment: Thanks!  This is really helpful.